# Configure classpath for WLST script - cannot import wlstutility lib

Tags: weblogic, classpath, wlst

I'm trying to create a weblogic domaine in my server using a wlst script. But i obtained a weird error about importing a "basic" library.

```
Problem invoking WLST - Traceback (innermost last):
  File "/logiciels/bea/weblogic_11gR1PS3/outil_de_creation_de_domaine_wls/wlst/wls11.pepsicash.zer334g0.py", line 33, in ?
NameError: wlstutility
```

I think the problem is in the classpath or an environement variable which is not defined yet. I see the "library" is in a folder in the same level as the script, and *wlstutility* is a folder which contains two files (**_*init*_.py**  **_*init*_.pyc**) with the same content.
In fact, i don't define any path for wlst and i'm pretty lost with it.

Comment: How are you starting your script? Do you source the `<weblogic home>/server/bin/setWLSEnv.sh` file? Can you run the `<weblogic home>/common/bin/wlst.sh` script ok?

Comment: Yes, the wlst.sh executes ok and launchs the wlst prompt. I have the setWLSEnv.sh in the path described, I launched it before executing the py script.